# FxCop Rules not available in Quality Profile Repository

Tags: sonarqube

We are trying to add FxCop rules to a C# Quality Profile

While we see the FxCop option in the Repository, no rules are available and shows as 0

[image: FxCop Repoistory shows 0 rules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happened: You went to the rules page from the quality profiles by clicking on "Sonar way". So, the filter has been automatically set to show only the rules that are active in that "Sonar way" quality profile, which doesn't include any FxCop one.

To see all the FxCop rules that are disabled, click on "inactive" next to "Sonar way C#", or simply uncheck "Quality Profile" to stop filtering on them.